# Crop video in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any flutter dart packages that can crop video dimensions? Or any way that it can be possible? I've used **video_player** and **chewie** for my project and I want to crop it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a powerful package that can crop videos and more: **flutter_ffmpeg** (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg)

My code in cropping a video and getting the output path (might be useful to someone)

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
String outputPath = appDocPath + "/output.mp4";
      await _flutterFFmpeg
          .execute(
              "-y -i $inputPath -c:v libx264 -filter:v crop=in_w:900 -c:a copy $outputPath")
          .then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

Comment: For more information about ffmpeg command line. This video will be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPV7JXTWPWI

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make a sliding crop window? so that it crops in each frame a different part of the video?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please try to check this :

https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer

Comment: Oh, what I meant is video's dimensions or pixel size. I'll edit my question. Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I may be little late to answer but i found this package last month which is good for cropping and trimming videos https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor/example